# Caused by android.os.BadParcelableException ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling:

Tags: android, android-studio, file

I'm getting BadParcelableException:  ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling when doing cut or copy operation.
tried multiple answers from stackoverflow but nothing works.

I've. tried changing writeTypedArray with writeParcelableArray but it didn't work out.
i am also unable to reproduce this error on my phone.

Log:

````
       at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2839)
       at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2765)
       at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableArray(Parcel.java:2873)
       at com.droidtechlab.filemanager.filesystem.PasteHelper.<init>(PasteHelper.java:80)
       at com.droidtechlab.filemanager.filesystem.PasteHelper.<init>(PasteHelper.java:56)
       at com.droidtechlab.filemanager.filesystem.PasteHelper$1.createFromParcel(PasteHelper.java:97)
       at com.droidtechlab.filemanager.filesystem.PasteHelper$1.createFromParcel(PasteHelper.java:95)
       at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2774)
       at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2668)
       at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3037)
       at android.os.BaseBundle.initializeFromParcelLocked(BaseBundle.java:288)
       at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:232)
       at android.os.BaseBundle.getBoolean(BaseBundle.java:894)
       at android.app.Activity.restoreHasCurrentPermissionRequest(Activity.java:7442)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7132)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2924)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3079)
       at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
       at```


Code:
````

public final class PasteHelper implements Parcelable {

```
public static final int OPERATION_COPY = 0, OPERATION_CUT = 1;

private int operation;
private HybridFileParcelable[] paths;
private Snackbar snackbar;
private MainActivity mainActivity;

public PasteHelper(MainActivity mainActivity, int op, HybridFileParcelable[] paths) {
    if (paths == null || paths.length == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(mainActivity, "Something went wrong, please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    operation = op;
    this.paths = paths;
    this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    showSnackbar();
}

private PasteHelper(Parcel in) {
    operation = in.readInt();
    paths =
            (HybridFileParcelable[])
                    in.readParcelableArray(HybridFileParcelable.class.getClassLoader());
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(operation);
    dest.writeTypedArray(paths, 0);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR =
        new Parcelable.Creator() {
            public PasteHelper createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new PasteHelper(in);
            }

            public PasteHelper[] newArray(int size) {
                return new PasteHelper[size];
            }
        };

public int getOperation() {
    return this.operation;
}

public HybridFileParcelable[] getPaths() {
    return paths;
}

/**
 * Invalidates the snackbar after fragment changes / reapply config changes. Keeping the contents
 * to copy/move intact
 *
 * @param mainActivity main activity
 * @param showSnackbar whether to show snackbar or hide
 */
public void invalidateSnackbar(MainActivity mainActivity, boolean showSnackbar) {
    this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    if (showSnackbar) {
        showSnackbar();
    } else {
        dismissSnackbar(false);
    }
}

/**
 * Dismisses snackbar and fab
 *
 * @param shouldClearPasteData should the paste data be cleared
 */
private void dismissSnackbar(boolean shouldClearPasteData) {
    if (snackbar != null) {
        snackbar.dismiss();
        snackbar = null;
    }
    if (shouldClearPasteData) {
        mainActivity.setPaste(null);
    }
    Utils.invalidateFab(mainActivity, null, false);
}

private void showSnackbar() {
    Single.fromCallable(() -> getSnackbarContent())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                    new SingleObserver<Spanned>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Spanned spanned) {
                            snackbar =
                                    Utils.showThemedSnackbar(
                                            mainActivity,
                                            spanned,
                                            BaseTransientBottomBar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE,
                                            R.string.paste,
                                            () -> {
                                                String path = mainActivity.getCurrentMainFragment().getCurrentPath();
                                                ArrayList<HybridFileParcelable> arrayList =
                                                        new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(paths));
                                                boolean move = operation == PasteHelper.OPERATION_CUT;
                                                new PrepareCopyTask(
                                                        mainActivity.getCurrentMainFragment(),
                                                        path,
                                                        move,
                                                        mainActivity,
                                                        mainActivity.isRootExplorer())
                                                        .executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, arrayList);
                                                dismissSnackbar(true);
                                            });
                            Utils.invalidateFab(mainActivity, () -> dismissSnackbar(true), true);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(@NotNull Throwable e) {
                            Timber.tag(PasteHelper.class.getSimpleName()).e("Failed to show paste snackbar due to "+ e.getCause());
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });
}

private Spanned getSnackbarContent() {
    String operationText = "<b>%s</b>";
    operationText =
            String.format(
                    operationText,
                    operation == OPERATION_COPY
                            ? mainActivity.getString(R.string.copy)
                            : mainActivity.getString(R.string.move));
    operationText = operationText.concat(": ");
    int foldersCount = 0;
    int filesCount = 0;
    for (HybridFileParcelable fileParcelable : paths) {
        if (fileParcelable.isDirectory(mainActivity.getApplicationContext())) {
            foldersCount++;
        } else {
            filesCount++;
        }
    }
    operationText =
            operationText.concat(
                    mainActivity.getString(R.string.folderfilecount, foldersCount, filesCount));

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        return Html.fromHtml(operationText, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT);
    } else {
        return Html.fromHtml(operationText);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you give more information about what are you trying to achieve? `MainActivity` as a private variable in a `Parcelable` class doesn't seem a good idea at all.

Comment: Agreed, it feels like `PasteHelper` should not be a `Parcelable`.